# How to set an Android "hidden" app inside PlayStore?

Tags: android, google-play-services

I have a subscription based web-service that allows you to  monitor industrial machines. It supports Raspberry PI and Android. 
Right now, the Android APK is downloaded from my website, but I want to put it in PlayStore to be able to push silent updates (most of the devices running it don't have a screen).

My question is how to make it "hidden" in PlayStore ?

I want only people coming with a link from my website to be able to download it. I want it to not appear in searches or in any Store listings (new apps, popular, etc). The only reason to have it in the store is for silent updates that are not possible in any other way.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is an official solution for this, but Apps with only Alpha and Beta apks are always hidden in the Playstore.

Comment: And are part of the auto update roll-out? I think they are not and the entire reason for me to have it in store is to have auto update

Comment: yes, once subscribed/added (depending on model) users receive updates like normal

Comment: I just tried this, but requires an additional step, opt-in url where they have to agree to "test" app. They are already paying customers, don't want to "test" anything, just to get the app. I think that I will just publish to production for now and add in description that is just for users already having a subscription with my service

Answer (score 0):

Google Play now allows you a new way to distribute internal applications(Google Play Private Channel):

> The Google Play Private Channel for Google Apps (the Private Channel)
>   allows Google Apps domains to distribute internal Android applications
>   to their users through the Google Play Store.

Here you can find the announce on Google [Enterprise Blog](http://googleforwork.blogspot.com/2012/12/a-new-way-to-distribute-your-internal.html) and [here](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2494992?hl=en) the instructions to set up this feature.

Comment: Thanks for response, I saw that, but that requires a Google App for business account and only users added to the business account will be able to install the application. This also requires to use email addresses registered on the business domain.